# How to integrate Karma with TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, karma-runner

I am able to run tests via Karma in TeamCity since you can run anything that's accessible via command line.  But, TeamCity only reports overall pass/fail -- does not report details of any failed tests.  If it fails, I just get "Process exited with code 1".

The karma homepage says there is a teamcity integration, but the [teamcity link](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/plus/Teamcity.html) says "Not available yet".

There seems to be a GIT project with [npm install package](https://npmjs.org/package/karma-teamcity-reporter).  But, the npm install failed with messages that don't mean much to me.

```
> npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-teamcity-reporter npm
> http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-teamcity-reporter npm http
> GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma npm http 304
> https://registry.npmjs.org/karma npm WARN `git config --get
> remote.origin.url` returned wrong result
> (git://github.com/vojtajina/node-di.git) undefined npm WARN `git
> config --get remote.origin.url` returned wrong result
> (git://github.com/vojtajina/node-di.git) undefined npm http GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/chokidar npm http GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io npm http GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/http-proxy npm http GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/glob npm http GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist npm http GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script npm http GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/0.6.0-1 npm http GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch npm http GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1 npm http GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/mime npm ERR! git clone
> git://github.com/vojtajina/node-di.git undefined npm ERR! git clone
> git://github.com/vojtajina/node-di.git undefined npm http GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/q npm http GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash npm http GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/log4js npm http GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf npm ERR! Error: spawn ENOENT npm
> ERR!     at errnoException (child_process.js:975:11) npm ERR!     at
> Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:766:34) npm ERR!
> If you need help, you may report this log at: npm ERR!    
> <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues> npm ERR! or email it to: npm
> ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
> 
> npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601 npm ERR! command "C:\\Program
> Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program
> Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
> "karma-teamcity-reporter" npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\steve npm ERR! node -v
> v0.10.5 npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18 npm ERR! syscall spawn npm ERR! code
> ENOENT npm ERR! errno ENOENT npm http 304
> https://registry.npmjs.org/chokidar npm http 304
> https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist npm http 304
> https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io npm http 304
> https://registry.npmjs.org/glob npm http 304
> https://registry.npmjs.org/http-proxy npm http 304
> https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script npm http 304
> https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/0.6.0-1 npm http 304
> https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch npm http 304
> https://registry.npmjs.org/mime npm http 304
> https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1 npm http 304
> https://registry.npmjs.org/q npm http 304
> https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash npm http 304
> https://registry.npmjs.org/log4js npm http 304
> https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf npm ERR!  npm ERR! Additional
> logging details can be found in: npm ERR!    
> C:\Users\steve\npm-debug.log npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I'm new to npm.  So maybe I'm doing something wrong with npm.  But, even if the npm install works, then what do I do?  Should I expect the next teamcity run of karma to include the special teamcity log messages?

Anyone know how to fully integrate Karma into teamcity?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use stable karma, which contains the teamcity reporter.

```
npm install -g karma
```

And then, use teamcity reporter, it will generate teamcity output on the stdout.

```
karma start --reporters teamcity --single-run
```

Comment: Super!  I already had karma installed.  All I had to do was update the command line in teamcity config.  Thanks!!

Comment: @Vojta: When I run this command on team city with PhantomJS as the browser the run never completes. Do you know what is causing this issue?

Comment: Possibly [this issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-teamcity-reporter/issues/5) - the writes need to be synchronous for TeamCity to report it.

Comment: @Vojta If I run `karma start --reporters teamcity --single-run` I get the following error:

    WARN [reporter]: Can not load "teamcity", it is not registered!
  Perhaps you are missing some plugin?

Comment: Perhaps you are missing a plugin - https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-teamcity-reporter

Comment: also you must run once: `npm install karma-teamcity-reporter`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343543/how-to-integrate-karma-with-teamcity